# Whats jQuery's equivalent of javascript's transport.responseText in Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to convert my Javascript's Ajax request to jQuery's ajax.
My Javascript Ajax:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            if (transport.responseText.length > 0) { 
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(transport.responseText);
                callback(obj);
            }    
        }    
    });
```

So how do I represent transport.responseText in jQuery?

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "POST",
        success: //how to handle the JSON response returned by the request
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go through the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: And especially through part about `success`: `Type: Function(Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)`

Comment: Is that Prototype.js? Please link the docs of `Ajax.Request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code snippet will work

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data,textStatus,jQXHR)
        {
           if(data){
               callback(data);
           }
        },
    });
```

Note: No need to use parseJSON method, as this ajax method returns JSON object.